# Bootstrap menu styling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cant for the life of me figure out how to style the bootstrap dropdown menus using CSS.

I can manage to get the background color to change but that's it. The links don't have an underline and the Hover background colour does not change. I haven't even started with the down arrows yet either!! Any advice?

Heres the code im trying:

```
#NAV .dropdown-menu { background-color:#273961; border-bottom: 5px solid #CCC;}
#NAV .dropdown-menu>li>a:link { background-color:#273961;}
#NAV .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover{ text-decoration: underline;}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew please read this: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and then create a [MCVE] in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this helps.

```
ul.dropdown-menu {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #CCC;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I was a little confused what you wanted to do with the background-color of the list items in your dropdown menu.  Here's an example of one way to change the background color when hovering over each link.  Using !important after a CSS attribute might help in some circumstances when you want to override any subsequent rules (but it might not be the BEST way to do this).
I recommend opening up your Chrome dev tools and playing around a bit until you get the desired results. I'm assuming you want to change the background-color of your list items when hovering to a different color than what you specified (#273961) since it is already that color to begin with?

```
.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: I had to put in "#NAV " before your code but worked like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: Great...glad to help Andrew!

Comment: Dont suppose you know how to style the .caret hover too?

Comment: hmm.  I would have to see the actual markup you have.  but I believe you can add a class to the caret and then add your css styling to that class.  If you simply want to add css styling to the `.caret` class it might interfere with any other potential carets you have on your website.  Also, you may need to over-ride bootstrap's styling of the caret by adding `!important` in your css as in: `.caret { color: red !important; }` .  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Brandon, that styles the caret but its the hover that causing me grief. Using .caret:hover doesn't work (p.s. i have upvoted your answer but im low level!)

Comment: Hmm...yeah, I'd have to see the actual markup.  What is happening when you hover over the caret?  What is it that you want to happen?